# Scanner cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

For some reason I get an error that scanner cannot be converted to int, even though I'm using  nextInt . why is that? complete noob here.

```
System.out.println("How many numbers does your array contains?") ;
Scanner num= new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner mis=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(num.nextInt());
int maara[]=new int[num]; 
for(int counter=0; counter<maara.length; counter++){
    System.out.println("enter num");
    System.out.println(mis.nextInt());
    maara[counter]=mis ;
```

I've searched a lot but the problem was always people using nextLine, here i'm stating that the input will be an integer and it's still won't run.
This is just part of the code, but i encounter this error alot. I've imported the scanner. 
Thank you very much in advance!

p.s. - I'm using netbeans on ubuntu 17.10. have no idea if that matters.

Comment: `maara[counter]=mis.nextInt();`?

Comment: `maara[counter]=mis;` Just as the error states, you cannot assign a Scanner to an int. `maara[counter]` is an int and `mis` is a Scanner.

Comment: thank you both for the answer. Alright, Considering I'm a noob I'll assume you're right. but why? I haven't used mis yet. I try to set the length of the array to num. I get the error on num, not mis.

Comment: I don't know how to say it any clearer. `maara[counter]` points to/should contain an int - a correct line of code would be like `maara[counter] = 1;` But instead of a 1, you tried to give `mis` which is a Scanner. You said, "take this Scanner and put it where I said an int should be." That just doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't " System.out.println(mis.nextInt());" turn it into an integer?

Comment: No, that just takes an `int` out of `mis` and prints it - it doesn't change `mis` into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

On this line `maara[counter]=mis;` you are attempting to put `mis` (the `Scanner`) into your `int` array.

You need to save the result of `nextInt()` and put that in.

```
int tmp = mis.nextInt();
System.out.println(tmp);
maara[counter] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is as usual. Replace your last two statement as

```
System.out.println(“Enter a number”);
int x = mis.nextInt();
maara[counter] = x;
```

Comment: Thank you! I now understand my whole view was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` is not an `int`. It's a thing that gives you `int`s if you ask in the right way.

It's like a supermarket: it will sell you milk, but it isn't milk itself. You have to buy the milk from the supermarket.

You need to assign something of type `int` to the array element:

```
maara[counter]=mis.nextInt();
```

But note that you don't want to do quite this, as you will get a different `int` (maybe) to the one you printed on the previous line, because you're asking for two values from the scanner. Instead, do something like:

```
int value = mis.nextInt();
System.out.println(value);
maara[counter] = value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the enrichment, and your time